# Access Panel to gas stove shutoff valve on other side of wall in laundry room to code?

Tags: gas, stove, shutoff, access-panel

My location is Burlington County, NJ

The cabinetry to the right side of the stove top cabinet has drawers in it. Typically I would put the access panel for the shutoff valve right in the side of an open cabinet.

I was thinking of an alternative solution since the room behind everything is the laundry room. Would it be to code if we put an access panel with the shutoff valve in the laundry room on the other side of the wall? It would be a short distance to go in there and shut it off. Before I do it I want to make sure it will be to code.

Also any other suggestions would be great.

Comment: You might need to let us know where you are - building codes vary round the world.

Comment: Burlington County, NJ 08010

Comment: Also if you can give me a website where I can check the exact code for that. That would be great also.

Comment: Sadly I can't (I'm in Scotland) but I'm sure someone here will be able to help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, putting the gas service shut-off in the laundry room would be fine (though they are typically found behind the appliance).  Remember, this is a *service disconnect valve* (for maintenance or replacement of the appliance) not an *emergency disconnect valve* (in the event of a gas leak).  The "emergency disconnect valve"  is at the meter since the first rule for gas leak safety is to exit the building.